# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: jsp

Hello Java and JSP gurus please help me sort out this. I have been trying to solve the problem for 2 weeks but have totally failed and it has really stressed me alot. I created three jsp files plus a java bean but have been getting an error message. 
These are the bin and class path roots.

CLASSPATH: **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;**
Path: **C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;**

First let me provide the jsp files and then the java bean files i have been working on. I'm very new to jsp.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD = POST ACTION = "SaveName.jsp">
What's your name ? <INPUT TYPE = TEXT NAME = username SIZE = 20 > <BR>
What's your e-mail?<INPUT TYPE = TEXT NAME = email SIZE = 20 > <BR>
What's your age ?  <INPUT TYPE = TEXT NAME = age SIZE = 4 >
<P> <INPUT TYPE = SUBMIT >
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

form.jsp

```
<jsp : useBean id = "user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"/>
<jsp : setProperty name = "user" property = "*"/>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<A HREF="NextPage.jsp">Continue</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

SaveName.jsp

```
<jsp : useBean id = "user" class = "user.UserData" scope = "session"/>
<HTML>
<BODY>
You entered<BR>
Name: <%= user.getUsername()%> <BR />
Email: <%= user.getEmail()%> <BR />
Age: <%= user.getAge()%> <BR />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

NextPage.jsp

I have saved the three files above in the following root path:
 **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\jsp pages**

```
package user;
public class UserData 
{

String username;
String email;
int age;

public void setUsername ( String value)

{
username=value;

}

public void setEmail ( String value)

{
email=value;

}

public void setAge ( int value)
{
age=value;

}

public String getUsername() 
{
return username;
}

public String getEmail()
{
return email;
}

public int getAge()
{
return age;
}

}
```

UserData.java compiled into UserData.class

I have saved the above java bean (.java and .class files) in the root folder below, though I just created the classes folder as it did not exist.
**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\user**

Here is the error code below.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /NextPage.jsp
user cannot be resolved
2: <HTML>
3: <BODY>
4: You entered<BR>
5: Name: <%= user.getUsername()%> <BR />
6: Email: <%= user.getEmail()%> <BR />
7: Age: <%= user.getAge()%> <BR />
8: </BODY>


An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /NextPage.jsp
user cannot be resolved
3: <BODY>
4: You entered<BR>
5: Name: <%= user.getUsername()%> <BR />
6: Email: <%= user.getEmail()%> <BR />
7: Age: <%= user.getAge()%> <BR />
8: </BODY>
9: </HTML>

An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /NextPage.jsp
user cannot be resolved
4: You entered<BR>
5: Name: <%= user.getUsername()%> <BR />
6: Email: <%= user.getEmail()%> <BR />
7: Age: <%= user.getAge()%> <BR />
8: </BODY>
9: </HTML>


 Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared:

```
<jsp : useBean id = "user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"/>
```

It means there is attribute named "user" in HttpSession.

You coded:

```
<%= user.getUsername()%>
```

It means there must be JSP VARIABLE named 'user'. So you are wrong.

**CORRECT WAY:**

```
${user.username}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code contribution it made a difference  but the problem now is, when i fill in the username and email and age they do not appear in the NextPage.jsp page(I mean the user data is not stored on the page). I receive it in such a format:    You entered  
Name:  
Email:  
Age:

Comment: It is another error. I indicated your compilation error. You need to fix compilation error first then asking another question.

Comment: I'm really lost, like I'm new to jsp, the statement: 'It is another error. I indicated your compilation error. You need to fix compilation error first then asking another question' - I'm wondering how to sort it out. Pliz Loc try to mentor me how to go about this compilation issue.

Comment: As I said. Don't use <%= user.getUsername()%>. Use ${user.username}

Comment: I did change to the ${user.username }, but the issue is when I feed in user data in the form.jsp page on my local host e.g Denis for User Name field; byansimedia@gmail.com for Email field; 22 for Age field;

Comment: I did change to the ${user.username }, but the issue is when I feed in user data in the form.jsp page on my local host e.g Denis for User Name field; byansimedia@gmail.com for Email field; 22 for Age field;   Denis and byansimedia@gmail.com and 22 are not appearing in the NextPage.jsp . why ? I no longer receive an error but the user data is not stored in the NextPage.jsp